# get screen height and width using java script in css

Tags: javascript, css

I want to retrieve width and height of screen so that i can set a division (body is given here)  to exact screen height irrespective of different screens , so is this the correct code for using script in css ?? 
        if no , please help me :

```
HTML FILE : 

<html>
    head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="helocss.css">


    </head>
    <body bgcolor="orange">


    </body>
    </html>
```

here is the css file   CSS FILE :

```
  body{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var w=screen.availWidth;
    var h=screen.availHeight;
    width: w;
    height: h;
    </script>


    }
```

Comment: You cannot have js in css file, and you cannot get exact width/height value. But there are several options in CSS that can help, using vh/vw units, media queries, calc operation, it all depends on what exactly you want to do with the values. If you simply want to set the body to be 100% of the viewport, you could use `width:100vw; height:100vh;`, vw/vh being percentage units of the view size

Answer (score 0):

first u can't use javascript in css
it should be in  
i am using jquery to done this

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
    <script>
      var width = $(window).width();
      var height = $(window).height();
      
      $("body").width(width).height(height);
        
     </script>


    </head>
    <body bgcolor="orange">


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can we use the same method to find height and width to divisions too ???? @patrick evans

Comment: if yes u can use that method to set or get height of any element